# How can I initialize only properties that have a value?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have a class **CustomControl** which inherits from **System.Windows.Forms.Control**.
I will also create a new class named **GraphicsData** which will have all the graphical information about my CustomControl (I need this because it's easier to serialize the data for saving it in a DB, json, etc.)

The CustomControl object will get the GraphicsData at the initialization(in the constructor) and I want it to get all the properties that have a value in GraphicsData (sometimes I don't want to initialize all of the properties from GraphicsData and I want them to remain the default from System.Windows.Forms.Control class).

The problem is that most of the proprierties are **not nullable**  and I cannot check if they are null so I can't do a simple:

```
customControl.BackColor = graphicsData.BackColor.HasValue ? graphicsData.BackColor.Value : BackColor;
```

I can of course work this around if I create my own Nullable class but this got really ugly and hard to understand the code. Also, it is very hard to add a new property when needed.

Now, what I did and I think this is a much cleaner way is the following:

**GraphicsData** class:

```
public class GraphicsData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<string> _initializedProperties = new List<string>();
    public List<string> InitializedProperties { get { return _initializedProperties; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Size _size;
    private Point _location;
    private AnchorStyles _anchor;
    private Color _backColor;
    private Image _backgroundImage;
    private Cursor _cursor;
    private Font _font;
    private Color _foreColor;
    private bool _enabled;
    private bool _visible;

    public Size Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set
        {
            _size = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Size");
        }
    }

    public Point Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set
        {
            _location = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Location");
        }
    }

    public AnchorStyles Anchor
    {
        get { return _anchor; }
        set
        {
            _anchor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Anchor");
        }
    }

    public Color BackColor
    {
        get { return _backColor; }
        set
        {
            _backColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BackColor");
        }
    }

    public Image BackgroundImage
    {
        get { return _backgroundImage; }
        set
        {
            _backgroundImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundImage");
        }
    }

    public Cursor Cursor
    {
        get { return _cursor; }
        set
        {
            _cursor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Cursor");
        }
    }

    public Font Font
    {
        get { return _font; }
        set
        {
            _font = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Font");
        }
    }

    public Color ForeColor
    {
        get { return _foreColor; }
        set
        {
            _foreColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ForeColor");
        }
    }

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return _enabled; }
        set
        {
            _enabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Enabled");
        }
    }

    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return _visible; }
        set
        {
            _visible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Visible");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (!_initializedProperties.Contains(propertyName))
            _initializedProperties.Add(propertyName);

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And in my custom control I have a method:

```
public void LoadGraphics()
    {
        var initializedProperties = graphics.InitializedProperties;
        foreach (string propertyName in initializedProperties)
        {
            var value = graphics.GetType()
                                .GetProperty(propertyName)
                                .GetValue(graphics, null);
            _customControl.GetType()
                          .GetProperty(propertyName)
                          .SetValue(_customControl, value, null);
        }
    }
```

Basically, I created a **List** named **InitializedProperties** and in the properties "set" I add the property in the list.
After that, using **reflection** in my **CustomControl**, I can load all the initialized properties.

I implemented the **INotifyPropertyChanged** because I also want to change the customControl properties each time a property is changed in GraphicsData.

Is this the proper way to do what I want ? I don't think the reflection code is that readable and I am concerned about the performance.

Comment: You can do the other way, pass your custom control to `GraphicsData` and inside property perform the update without reflection: `_backColor = value; owner.BackColor = value;`.

Comment: Oh yeah, now I realized that I can do that too. I don't know what I was thinking today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using nullable values is a much easier method for achieving this.

C# already has a built-in `Nullable` class, but it also offers a simple way to make a value nullable without the excess verbosity that the `Nullable` class introduces: `?`.

All of your values can be made nullable by appending the `?` operator to the value types:

```
private Size? _size;
private Point? _location;
private AnchorStyles? _anchor;
private Color? _backColor;
private Image _backgroundImage;
private Cursor _cursor;
private Font _font;
private Color? _foreColor;
private bool? _enabled;
private bool? _visible;
```

Your `LoadGraphics` method can easily check to see if the GraphicsData property has a non-null value, and set the corresponding control property if so.

```
public void LoadGraphics(GraphicsData gfx)
{
    // It may be permissible to utilize a null value for BackgroundImage!
    // In this case, utilizing a separate field (IsBackgroundImageSet) may be a necessary
    if (gfx.BackgroundImage != null) { _customControl.BackgroundImage = gfx.BackgroundImage; }

    if (gfx.Size != null) { _customControl.Size = gfx.Size.Value; }
    if (gfx.Location != null) { _customControl.Location = gfx.Location.Value }
    if (gfx.Anchor != null) { _customControl.Anchor = gfx.Anchor.Value; }
    if (gfx.BackColor != null) { _customControl.BackColor = gfx.BackColor .Value; }
    if (gfx.Cursor != null) { _customControl.Cursor = gfx.Cursor; }
    if (gfx.Font != null) { _customControl.Font = gfx.Font; }
    if (gfx.Color != null) { _customControl.Color = gfx.Color.Value; }
    if (gfx.Enabled != null) { _customControl.Enabled = gfx.Enabled.Value; }
    if (gfx.Visible != null) { _customControl.Visible = gfx.Visible.Value; }
}
```

Comment: This is what I want to AVOID.

Comment: Basically, if I will do customControl.BackgroundImage = graphis.BackgroundImage which doesnt have the '?' operator, I will override the default backgroundImage in the Control class or even get an error

Comment: I don't believe you do. If you are looking into using reflection to check for set properties, you've already strayed from the easy path. Using nullable values is by far the easier method.

Comment: Ok, I get the '?' operator and I can use it for sure but I am concerned about the Image, Cursor and Font. Won't I get the error "object reference not set to an instance of object" when I do _customControl.Cursor = graphics.Cursor; if I don't initialize the Cursor property whithin Graphics?

Comment: Take a look at the updated code. One thing you will need to determine is whether a null value is permitted for a property, or if it represents a missing value. In the case of Size, a null value represents a missing value, and the GraphicsData value should simply not be copied over. In the case of BackgroundImage, a null value is likely a permissible value. In the case of Cursor it likely is not. Therefore, some error handling code (which may be as simple as defaulting to Cursors.Default) may be warranted.

Comment: Okay, I understand, I tried the solution you provided at first but I had some errors and after that over complicated myself. But now I see the point and how it works. Thanks!